# Latex, small letters in running chapter title, book

Tags: formatting, header-footer

Say I have the chapter titled "My favorite equation $E=mc^2$", document class book.
How do I prevent Latex from capitalizing the mc^2 in the running title?

That is I want the running title to be "MY FAVORITE EQUATION $E=mc^2$" but not "MY FAVORITE EQUATION $E=MC^2$.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!